# Getting element's name in XPATH

Tags: xpath, elementname

If I selected an element using XPATH how can I get its name?
I mean something like `text()` function in `//element/[@id=elid]/text()`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use [`name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-name). (Find docs for newer versions of the XPath language [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/all/).)

Here are modified versions of your example:

**Works in XPath 2.0+ only:**

```
//element/*[@id='elid']/name()
```

**Works in XPath 1.0 and 2.0+*:**

```
name(//element/*[@id='elid'])
```

*If using 2.0+, the expression `//element/*[@id='elid']` must only return one element. Otherwise you'll get an error like `A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:name()`

You could also use [`local-name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name) which returns the local part of the [expanded name](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-expanded-name) (without any namespace prefix).

Answer (score 2):

The tag names tree can also be obtained with

```
echo "du //Element/*" | xmllint --shell response-02.xml
Ele1
    id
    name
    Nested1
        id
        name
Ele2
```