# 'local-name()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence) T-SQL Xquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

This is a variation/combination of these two questions, but I think I've done as they described:

- [Getting element's name in XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984508/getting-elements-name-in-xpath)
- [XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940566/xquery-value-value-requires-a-singleton-or-empty-sequence-found-oper)

Is there a way to get the name of a node in a SQL Server 2016 T-SQL query?

I want to do this:

```
select 
    trcid,
    trcXML.value(
        'local-name(//*[local-name()="after"][1]/*[1])',  
        'varchar(32)'
    ) as XmlTableName,
    trcXml, 
    trcGUID, 
    trcCorrID 
from trace 
order by trcId desc
```

I have explicitly included the `[1]` after each item in the hierarchy.

> Error: XQuery [trace.trcXML.value()]: 'local-name()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type `'element(*,xdt:untyped) *'`

Sample data:

```
<s1:DB2Request xmlns:s1="XYZDB2">
  <s1:sync>
    <s1:after identityInsert="false">
      <s1:PG204AT5>
        <s1:ISA06>1975111</s1:ISA06>
           etc... 
      </s1:PG204AT5>
    </s1:after>
  </s1:sync>
</s1:DB2Request>
```

I want the table name (this is a BizTalk "update-gram") which is between the "after" and the ISA06 elements, in this case: PG204AT5.

Tested in xpathtester.com: `local-name(//*[local-name()="after"][1]/* [1])` 
 - for some reason when I save it the XPATH gets changed: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/2bd602d8fc7aee0484de14bf93f71ef2

Comment: What do you mean by Node? Is it Server name? SELECT
 @@servername AS 'Server Name' 
,@@servicename AS 'Instance Name'
,DB_NAME() AS 'Database Name'
,HOST_NAME() AS 'Host Name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more set of parenthesis gives you a singleton as required:

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE(s XML);
INSERT INTO @t(s)VALUES(N'<s1:DB2Request xmlns:s1="XYZDB2">
  <s1:sync>
    <s1:after identityInsert="false">
      <s1:PG204AT5>
        <s1:ISA06>1975111</s1:ISA06>
           <somethingsomething/>
      </s1:PG204AT5>
    </s1:after>
  </s1:sync>
</s1:DB2Request>');

select 
    s.value(
        'local-name((//*[local-name()="after"][1]/*)[1])',  
        'varchar(32)'
    ) as XmlTableName
from @t;
```

Results in:

```
XmlTableName
PG204AT5
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the SQL Server engine, unlike most XQuery implementations, does "pessimistic static typing" - it assumes that if things can go wrong, they will go wrong.

The expression `//*[local-name()="after"][1]/* [1]` is capable of returning more than one element - for example it will do so with this input

```
<x>
  <y>
    <after>
       <z/>
    </after>
  </y>
  <y>
    <after>
       <z/>
    </after>
  </y>
</x>
```

so the XQuery compiler infers a static type of element()*, which doesn't meet the requirement.

It's probably enough to simply do `(//*[local-name()="after"]/*)[1]`.

Personally, I always thought pessimistic static typing was a really poor design choice, but some of the early XQuery implementors including Microsoft were very keen on it.

Comment: I'm fuzzy on why putting the first [1] without the parentheses doesn't act as a subscript.  Is the parser doing something else with it or ignoring it totally?

Comment: `//X[1]` parses as `/descendant-or-self::node()/(child::X[1])` which returns every X that is the first child of its parent. By contrast, `(//X)[1] finds all the X elements in the document and then selects the first.

Answer (score 2):

Or even simpler solution by asking explicitly first child node name of the `<s1:after>` element.

> SQL

```sql
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl(xmldata)
VALUES(N'<s1:DB2Request xmlns:s1="XYZDB2">
  <s1:sync>
    <s1:after identityInsert="false">
      <s1:PG204AT5>
        <s1:ISA06>1975111</s1:ISA06>
           <somethingsomething/>
      </s1:PG204AT5>
    </s1:after>
  </s1:sync>
</s1:DB2Request>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'XYZDB2')
SELECT xmldata.value('local-name((/DB2Request/sync/after/child::node())[1])','VARCHAR(50)') as XmlTableName
FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
+--------------+
| XmlTableName |
+--------------+
| PG204AT5     |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I selected TT.'s approach so I wouldn't have to specify the namespace.

Comment: The namespace is not mandatory. You can use a  namespace wildcard. Check it out: **SELECT xmldata.value('local-name((//*:after/child::node())[1])','VARCHAR(50)') as XmlTableName
FROM @tbl;**

Comment: I think the main point was that I needed parentheses around everything in front of the final [1].

Comment: There is no need to call the **local-name()** function twice.

Comment: I actually didn't know about the "namespace wildcard" - found good blog here that explains: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/namespace-wildcards-in-xpath/

Comment: SQL Server supports a subset of XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0. That's why namespace wildcards functionality is in place.