# Get Name of Nodes Attributes of an XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, tree, attributes, nodes

I'm trying to get names of attributes nodes of an XML file..i'm able to read nodes and attributes value but not names.
In this xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Root>
-<body surname="Rott" name="Pig">
<city>London</city>
</body>
-<body surname="Lip" name="Jack">
<city>Los Angeles</city>
</body>
-<body colorB="White" colorA="Yellow">
<city>Rome</city>
</body>
</Root>
```

I'm trying to get "surname", "name", "colorB", "colorA" etc.

I do this vb.net example but I cannot get attribute (need something like a reader.GetNameAttribute command)? Does it exists?

I tryed to do this program:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim filePath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
Me.Text = filePath
Dim docXML As New XmlDocument
docXML.Load(filePath)
Dim reader As XmlNodeReader = New XmlNodeReader(docXML)


While reader.Read

    Dim lettura = reader.NodeType
    Dim valueA As String
    Dim attr_name As String = "none"
    'attr_name = reader.GetNameAttribute()     here ? get name attribute????


    valueA = reader.Name
    If reader.HasAttributes Then

        Dim conteggio As Integer = reader.AttributeCount
        For x = 0 To conteggio - 1
            MsgBox("Node is: " + valueA + " and has an attribute named: " + attr_name + " = " + reader.GetAttribute(x))
        Next
    End If



End While
```

Comment: Valid for attributes too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7984537/2834978 as `name(//path/to/@attribute)`

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```vb
Dim xe As XElement ' = XElement.Load(filePath) 'for production
' for testing used literal
xe = <Root>
         <body surname="Rott" name="Pig">
             <city>London</city>
         </body>
         <body surname="Lip" name="Jack">
             <city>Los Angeles</city>
         </body>
         <body colorB="White" colorA="Yellow">
             <city>Rome</city>
         </body>
     </Root>

Dim nms As New List(Of String)

'get body nodes attributes names

nms = (From el In xe...<body>
         From attr In el.Attributes
           Select attr.Name.LocalName).ToList
```

If you want only one occurrence of the attribute names change .ToList  to  .Distinct.ToList